# Is validation set necessary in neural networks while cross validation alone works well in regression based models?

Tags: validation, neural-network, regression, cross-validation

Do we need the validation in neural networks because neural networks do not always converge to the same answer? 
I have never heard of a validation set in models such as regression or ensemble learning. We cross validate our dataset entirely. dividing it into k-fold train and test sets.  however for neural networks we also need a validation set that we extract from the training set. Now I know why we need the validation set in neural networks. What I need to know is why we don't do the same procedure in let's say logistic regression.

Comment: A logistic regression is deterministic and a neural net isn't.

Comment: Is that the reason for the validation set? That's what I recon but I can't find a reference for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat good discussion on the purpose of the training, testing and validation sets [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set).

As for the need of a testing set, if you are not modifying any parameters of your model, there probably isn't much of a need for a second set to test on.  A neural network has a large number of parameters that can be adjusted (hidden layers, number of neurons, training runs, epochs, momentum, learning rate, etc.) that can be influenced by the results of the validation set.  Using this additional testing set can be used to confirm that a model generalises well on unseen testing data after the model has been tuned (further alterations should not occur once the testing set has been completed).

I have also used a testing set for ensemble configurations in the past where the model had some adjustable parameters (number of ensemble members, combination parameters) and this also verified its ability to estimate unseen testing data after tuning.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well Thanks Matt. I read the link, it was rather on the spot.